# C++ memory address and offset reading - 64 Bit

Tags: c++, memory, 64-bit, offset

I'm having some trouble with trying to calculate an memory address with a offset.

*NOTE: I can do 32 bit, but I need to use 64-bit addresses.*

The example I have is this address: 0x000002586F08CE30 with offset 0x88.
When I get this add it has the address of : 0x2586F08CEB8 when it should be : 0x25825C4C880

I have tried this:

```
void aVoid()
{
    DWORD64* add = (DWORD64*)0x000002586F08CE30;
    cout << add << endl;

    DWORD64* off = (DWORD64*)0x88;
    cout << off << endl;

    DWORD64* BaseTimeAddress = (DWORD64*)((char*)add + (DWORD64)off);
    cout << BaseTimeAddress << endl;    // Gets 000002586F08CEB8
}
```

[image: Offsets with the right addresses]
Where I got 0x25825C4C880 at : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K4eP.png)

FULL CODE

```
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

`
using namespace std;

DWORD GetModuleBaseAddress(TCHAR* lpszModuleName, DWORD pID) {
    DWORD dwModuleBaseAddress = 0;
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, pID); // make snapshot of all modules within process
    MODULEENTRY32 ModuleEntry32 = { 0 };
    ModuleEntry32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
    
    if (Module32First(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32)) //store first Module in ModuleEntry32
    {
        do {
            if (_tcscmp(ModuleEntry32.szModule, lpszModuleName) == 0) // if Found Module matches Module we look for -> done!
            {
                dwModuleBaseAddress = (DWORD_PTR)ModuleEntry32.modBaseAddr;
                break;
            }
        } while (Module32Next(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32)); // go through Module entries in Snapshot and store in ModuleEntry32


    }
    CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    return dwModuleBaseAddress;
}

DWORD GetPointerAddress(HWND hwnd, DWORD gameBaseAddr, DWORD address, vector<DWORD> offsets)
{
    DWORD pID = NULL; // Game process ID
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pID);
    HANDLE phandle = NULL;
    phandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pID);
    if (phandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || phandle == NULL);

    DWORD offset_null = NULL;
    ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPVOID*)(gameBaseAddr + address), &offset_null, sizeof(offset_null), 0);
    DWORD pointeraddress = offset_null; // the address we need

    for (int i = 0; i < offsets.size() - 1; i++) // we dont want to change the last offset value so we do -1
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPVOID*)(pointeraddress + offsets.at(i)), &pointeraddress, sizeof(pointeraddress), 0);
        //cout << "ADD: " << &pointeraddress << endl;
    }
    return pointeraddress += offsets.at(offsets.size() - 1); // adding the last offset
}

#include <Psapi.h>

DWORD_PTR GetProcessBaseAddress(DWORD processID)
{
    DWORD_PTR   baseAddress = 0;
    HANDLE      processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID);
    HMODULE* moduleArray;
    LPBYTE      moduleArrayBytes;
    DWORD       bytesRequired;

    if (processHandle)
    {
        if (EnumProcessModules(processHandle, NULL, 0, &bytesRequired))
        {
            if (bytesRequired)
            {
                moduleArrayBytes = (LPBYTE)LocalAlloc(LPTR, bytesRequired);

                if (moduleArrayBytes)
                {
                    unsigned int moduleCount;

                    moduleCount = bytesRequired / sizeof(HMODULE);
                    moduleArray = (HMODULE*)moduleArrayBytes;

                    if (EnumProcessModules(processHandle, moduleArray, bytesRequired, &bytesRequired))
                    {
                        baseAddress = (DWORD_PTR)moduleArray[0];
                    }

                    LocalFree(moduleArrayBytes);
                }
            }
        }

        CloseHandle(processHandle);
    }

    return baseAddress;
}

int main() {
    //HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Halo Wars: Definitive Edition");
    //char gameModule1[] = "xgameFinal.exe";
    DWORD64 address = 0x00000258722B0AB0;

    float nVal = 2000;

    HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(0, "Halo Wars: Definitive Edition");
    if (hWnd == 0) {
        cerr << "Could not find window." << endl;
    }
    else {
        DWORD PID;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &PID);
        HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, PID);

        if (!hProc) {
            cerr << "Cannot open process." << endl;
        }
        else {



            DWORD64* add = (DWORD64*)0x000002586F08CE30;
            cout << add << endl;

            DWORD64* off = (DWORD64*)0x88;
            cout << off << endl;


            DWORD64* BaseTimeAddress = (DWORD64*)((char*)add + (DWORD64)off);
            cout << BaseTimeAddress << endl;

            DWORD64* com = (DWORD64*)add;
            cout << com << endl;
            //cout << &add << endl;


            DWORD_PTR baseAddr2 = GetProcessBaseAddress(PID);
            cout << "base" << &baseAddr2 << endl;
            cout << "base"<<baseAddr2 << endl;
            cout << "base" <<hex<< baseAddr2 << endl;
            DWORD64 offset_null = NULL;
            DWORD64 add2 = ReadProcessMemory(hWnd, (LPVOID*)(baseAddr2 + 0x014FA250), &offset_null, sizeof(offset_null), 0);
            cout << &add2 << endl;

            cout << &offset_null << endl;

            ReadProcessMemory(hWnd, (LPVOID*)(baseAddr2 + 0x014FA250 + 0x88+0x8+0x110), &offset_null, sizeof(offset_null), 0);
            cout << &offset_null << endl;

            cout << "END";









            char gameModule1[] = "xgameFinal.exe";
            DWORD_PTR baseAddr1 = GetProcessBaseAddress(PID);
            cout << hex << baseAddr1 << endl;
            cout << &baseAddr1 << endl;
            DWORD64 baseAddr = GetModuleBaseAddress(_T(gameModule1), PID);

            /*
            
            char gameModule1[] = "ac_client.exe";

            DWORD baseAddr = GetModuleBaseAddress(_T(gameModule1), procID);
            DWORD pointsAddr = 0x0018AC00;
            vector<DWORD> pointsOffesets = { 0x11C };
            //cout << std::hex << pointsAddr << endl;
            DWORD pointsPtrAddr = GetPointerAddress(hWnd, baseAddr, pointsAddr, pointsOffesets);
            //010FF974
            //cout << pointsPtrAddr << endl << &pointsPtrAddr << endl;
            int val = 1;


            ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID*)(pointsPtrAddr), &val, sizeof(val), 0);
            cout << "Value: " << val << endl;

            cout << "Pointer Address: " << std::hex << pointsPtrAddr << endl;

            cout << "WORKS";
            //"xgameFinal.exe"+016208B0
            */




          /*  DWORD64* BaseAddress = (DWORD64*)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
            DWORD64* address = (DWORD64*)((char*)BaseAddress + 0x014FA250);
            address = (DWORD64*)((char*)*address + 0x88 + 0x8 + 0x110);
            float currentTime = *(float*)address;

            cout << currentTime;
            cout << "END";
            */







            ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (LPVOID)address, &nVal, (DWORD64)sizeof(nVal), NULL);
            cout << nVal;
            CloseHandle(hProc);

            cin.get();

        }

    }
    return 0;

}
`
```

Comment: Can you explain, exactly why "it should be : 0x25825C4C880"? Can you show your work, that produced this result?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, within the post I have a image that has text on it called (Offsets with the right addresses.). But if you open that image up you can see the CE(cheat engine) has all the correct address which is what I'm trying to figure out in c++.

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Can you [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text? All code ***must meet all requirements for a [mre]***. You'll find many other questions here, with a [mre], in plain text. Please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I made the image link into a plaintext, sorry first time posting.

Comment: That's pretty weird "plaintext", with lines, boxes, multiple fonts, and icons.

Comment: The screen shot says `[2586F08CE30 + 88]` but you calculated `2586F08CE30 + 88`.

Comment: @RaymondChen I see what you mean, but are you sure that has anything to do with this? If so can you please provide an example on how the calculation is different?

Comment: Use a calculator. `0x000002586F08CE30 + 0x88 = 0x2586F08CEB8`. Your program adds the offset to the address correctly. But that's not what the tool is doing

Comment: @RaymondChen Sorry I'm pretty new with memory, but I do understand what you mean now. Thank you for your help! I wouldn't have been able to solve this as fast as I did without your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I do want to give a shoutout to @Jeffrey and @RaymondChen for their posts that helped me think better about this problem.

So real quick I'll post the code below and after that explain it more:

```
void code()
{
    /*1*/ DWORD64* test6 = (DWORD64*)0x2586F08CE30; cout << test6 << endl;
    /*2*/ DWORD64* test7 = (DWORD64*)0x88; cout << test7 << endl;
    /*3*/ DWORD64* test8;
    /*4*/ DWORD64* test9;
    /*5*/ ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (LPVOID*)((DWORD64)test6+ (DWORD64)test7), &test8, sizeof(test8), 0);
    /*6*/ ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (LPVOID*)((DWORD64)test8 + (DWORD64)0x8), &test9, sizeof(test9), 0);
    /*7*/ DWORD64* test2 = (DWORD64*)0x110;
    /*8*/ //cout << test2 << endl;
    /*9*/ DWORD64* test3 = (DWORD64*)((char*)test9 + (DWORD64)test2);
    /*10*/ //cout << test3 << endl;
    /*11*/ float currentTime = 0;
    /*12*/ ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (LPVOID*)test3, &currentTime, sizeof(currentTime), 0);
    /*13*/ //cout << test3 << endl;
    /*14*/ cout << currentTime << endl;
}
```

Here is the image from cheat engine that has all the data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K4eP.png

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K4eP.png)

So I started with 0x2586F08CE30 which I get from cheat engine right now, but "xgameFinal.exe"+014FA250 = 0x2586F08CE30

So next I need to take that address and combine it with offset 0x88, at line 5 I do that.

Next is to take that address from test8 and combine offset 0x8. (@ line 6)

Next is the last offset (0x110), this is where @RaymondChen comment helped me out.

> The screen shot says [2586F08CE30 + 88] but you calculated 2586F08CE30 + 88. –
> Raymond Chen

So at line 9 is where I get the final address and then also the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
DWORD64* BaseTimeAddress = (DWORD64*)((char*)add + (DWORD64)off);
```

By doing `(char*)add`, you make the `+` operator add an offset in char. Chars are 1-byte. As such,

```
0x000002586F08CE30 + 0x88 = 0x2586F08CEB8
```

is correct. The other address you specify is wildly off. Where did you get it from?

In the image you link, there is a type field. You probably need to change your line to typecast to this type:

```
DWORD64* BaseTimeAddress = (DWORD64*)((float*)add + (DWORD64)off);
```

This means: Offset `add`, by `off` number of `float`s. This type of low-level modifications of pointers, though, can easily lead to undefined behaviour in C++, unless you are very careful. You need to understand `reinterpret_cast`s and their limitations.

Comment: I got the other address from cheat engine. (the image is the link called : Offsets with the right addresses.) If so, how would I be able to get the address that I want in how cheat engine gets it?

Comment: Image address as well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K4eP.png